# Printing jsonp with console or alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call an API using AJAX. When I query the api on my browser I receive my JSON.

The status code is a 200 ok which means I am on the right track. If I preview in network chrome or network response I see the JSON data. The question is how do I use it? I cannot seem to make it pop an alert or print in the console. Please help?
My code is as below:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var pm_url = 'http://xxx.xxxx./accounts?callback=photos';
    $.ajax({
        url: pm_url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'photos',
        jsonp: 'callback',
    });
});
function photos (data) {
    alert(data);
    console.log(data);
};`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call should be like this. Remove the quotes on the function name

```
$.ajax({
    url: pm_url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: photos,
    jsonp: 'callback',
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I can see my data is now undefined in console which is obviously a step in the right direction. I'm currently trying to see how i can parse it back to json. If you know then you can make my life easier by telling me know. thanks again Weedoze

Comment: Are you sure that the datatype is `jsonp` ?

Comment: Yes if i call using JSON i get the cross domain error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.xxx/accounts?callback=photos. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. So i used jsonp.